# group by on two columns one of which is timestamp

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have a SQL data table which contains data as follows:

```
t_id   |  s_id   |  timestamp                 | column1   | column2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
111    | 312552  | 2019-01-01 13:00:00.000000 | 8.8911    | 12.1123
111    | 412522  | 2019-01-01 14:00:00.000000 | 8.0001    | 22.1234
111    | 112999  | 2019-01-01 15:00:00.000000 | 18.8901   | 42.9746
111    | 312555  | 2019-01-01 16:00:00.000000 | 0.1195    | 11.5824
...
...
...
222    | 332552  | 2019-01-01 13:00:00.000000 | 0.0011    | 33.1323
222    | 442522  | 2019-01-01 14:00:00.000000 | 8.5501    | 20.1111
222    | 112465  | 2019-01-01 15:00:00.000000 | 1.0905    | 40.1476
222    | 313333  | 2019-01-01 16:00:00.000000 | 5.2295    | 14.4444
...
...
345    | 333352  | 2019-01-01 13:00:00.000000 | 0.0011    | 12.9045
345    | 444422  | 2019-01-01 14:00:00.000000 | 8.5501    | 2.50476
345    | 112265  | 2019-01-01 15:00:00.000000 | 1.0905    | 90.1111
345    | 316633  | 2019-01-01 16:00:00.000000 | 5.2295    | 44.0000
```

In the table, each `s_id` corresponds to a unique `t_id`. The `timestamp` column represents one full year (8760 hours) for each `s_id`. I want to process this data such that for each `t_id`, the output data has the following columns:

```
t_id   | timestamp                  | sum_column1  | sum_column2
----------------------------------------------------------------
111    | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | 8998.8911    | 111112.1123
........ (rest of 8759 hours for t_id = 111) ....................

222    | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | 1111.1234    | 965464.1123
........ (rest of 8759 hours for t_id = 222) ....................
```

where `sum_column1` should be sum of column1 grouped by t_id and timestamp, and same for `sum_column2`

The query I wrote for this (shown below) doesn't work as below, but works if I put the `timestamp` inside a `date()` function. But in the latter case, it is simply **date**, (not **datetime**, which is the expected result). How can this query be modified to output results grouped by `t_id` and also report `timestamp`

```
select
    t_id,
    timestamp,
    sum(column1) as sum_column1, 
    sum(column2) as sum_column2
from
    data_table 
where
    t_id in (111, 222)
group by 
    timestamp,
    t_id
order by
    timestamp, 
    t_id
```

The query results in following error message, But I don't see any syntax error:

> Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "," Position: 37;

PS: I'm working on Amazon Redshift

Comment: I don't understand what your result set consists of.  Are all the timestamps concatenated together or in different rows.

Comment: I get an error: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "," Position: 37;

Comment: What is it about your query that you think doesn't work?  If you use date(), it will truncate the time off, summarising the data per date rather than per hour, so it doesn't sound like that's what you're after.  If you just move timestamp to be the 2nd column to order by, doesn't that give you the result you need? (all that does it change the order in which results are presented, but bunches them together by t_id, like in the example of your desired result)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use window functions rather than aggregation:

```
select
    t_id,
    "timestamp",
    sum(column1) over (partition by t_id) as sum_column1, 
    sum(column2) over (partition by t_id) as sum_column2
from
    data_table 
where
    t_id in (111, 222)
order by
    t_id,
    "timestamp"
```

PostgreSQL [demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kku3XHLnvyqtmX9ixGL2vM/1)

Comment: I tried this, and this results in the following: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "," Position: 37; (I get the similar error with the original query in the question above, but I don't see any error in syntax)

Comment: @Vakratund it's definitely valid postgresql syntax, see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kku3XHLnvyqtmX9ixGL2vM/0 and I can't see anything about it that looks wrong for redshift.

Comment: @Vakratund is there any more information in the error message than that?

Comment: my syntax also seems ok to me. there is no more information in the error message.

Comment: Perhaps it's actually coming in from the code you're using to execute the query? Can you share that?

Comment: @Vakratund had a thought - it might be because redshift is more fussy about the use of timestamp as a column name. What happens if you escape it as I have done in my edit?

Comment: @Vakratund did my change help?